# 500 (Internal Server Error) when I try to delete an event in my calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to delete an event in the full calendar in the website .But every time I hit the button does not delete , I get message `undefined` ,I go  to the console and I get the following error :
[image]

I have tried adding this script based on my research :

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })
```

But still get the same error

I have tried to add this line of code too :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but that did not make difference to .

This my caledar.blade.php class:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ config('calendar') }}">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Full Calendar</title>

    {!! Html::style('vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}
    {!! Html::style('vendor2/seguce92/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css') !!}
    {!! Html::style('vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css') !!}
    {!! Html::style('vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css') !!}

</head>

<div id='app'></div>
<div class='container'></div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="color:#fff">
    <div class="navbar-inner" >
        <!-- Branding Image -->
        <div id="app">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                    @if (Auth::guest())

                    @else

                    @endif
                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                        <!-- Branding Image -->
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                            {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}

                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                        <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            &nbsp; @if (Auth::guest())

                            @else

                            @endif
                            <li>
                                <div class="for-group" style="padding-top:10px;">
                                    <input type="text" id="searching_for" placeholder="Search for a user" style="width: 300px;" class="form-control">

                                </div>

                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/front') }}">
                            {{ config('front', 'Nearby') }}

                        </a>

                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/suggest') }}">
                            {{ config('suggest', 'Suggest Me') }}

                        </a>

                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/calendar') }}">
                            {{ config('calendar', 'Events') }}

                        </a>

                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/home') }}">
                            {{ config('home', 'Home') }}

                        </a>

                        <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                            <!-- Authentication Links -->
                            @if (Auth::guest())

                                <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>

                            @else
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                        {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="{{url('/home')}}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-cogs"></i>Home</a></li>

                                        <li><a href="{{url('/profile/'.Auth::user()->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>My Profile</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{url('/settings')}}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-cogs"></i>Settings</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{url('/front')}}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-cogs"></i>Map</a></li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                               onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                                Logout
                                            </a>



                                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                            </form>
                                        </li>







                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            @yield('content')
        </div>
</div>
</div>
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'user.events.store', 'method' => 'post', 'role' => 'form']) }}
<div id="responsive-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static"->

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>Registration of new Event</h4>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('title','Title') }}
                {{Form::text('title',old('title'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('date_start','Date Start') }}
            {{Form::text('date_start',old('date_start'),['class' => 'form-control','readonly'=>'true'])}}
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('time_start','Time Start') }}
                {{Form::text('time_start',old('time_start'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('date_end','Time Finish') }}
                {{Form::text('date_end',old('date_end'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('color','COLOR') }}
                <div class="input-group colorpicker">
                    {{ Form::text('color',old('color'),['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                    <span class ="input-group-addon">

                        <i></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            {!! Form::submit('Save',['class' => 'btn-btn-success'])!!}

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
{{Form::close()}}
<div id='calendar'></div>


<div id="modal-event" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static"->

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Details of new Event</h4>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('_title','Title') }}
                    {{Form::text('_title',old('_title'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('_date_start','Date Start') }}
                    {{Form::text('_date_start',old('_date_start'),['class' => 'form-control','readonly'=>'true'])}}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('_time_start','Time Start') }}
                    {{Form::text('_time_start',old('_time_start'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('_date_end','Time Finish') }}
                    {{Form::text('_date_end',old('_date_end'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('_color','COLOR') }}
                    <div class="input-group colorpicker">
                        {{ Form::text('_color',old('_color'),['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                        <span class ="input-group-addon">

                        <i></i>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a id="delete" data-href="{{url('events')}}"data-id="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>


                {!! Form::submit('Update',['class' => 'btn btn-success'])!!}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


</body>

{!! Html::script('vendor2/seguce92/jquery.min.js') !!}
{!! Html::script('vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') !!}
{!! Html::script('vendor2/seguce92/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js') !!}
{!! Html::script('vendor2/seguce92/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js') !!}
{!! Html::script('vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js') !!}
{!! Html::script('vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap-colorpicker/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js') !!}
<script>

var BASEURL="{{url('/')}}";
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },

            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            selectable:true,
            selectHelper:true,

            select:function(start){
                start = moment(start.format());

                $('#date_start').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                $('#responsive-modal').modal('show');
            },
            events: BASEURL+'/events',

            eventClick: function(event, jsEvent,view){
                var date_start = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                var time_start = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('hh:mm:ss');
                var date_end = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
                $('#modal-event #delete').attr('data-id',event.id);
                $('#modal-event #_title').val(event.title);
                $('#modal-event #_date_start').val(date_start);
                $('#modal-event #_time_start').val(time_start);
                $('#modal-event #_date_end').val(date_end);
                $('#modal-event #_color').val(event.color);
                $('#modal-event').modal('show');

            }

        });

    });

    $('.colorpicker').colorpicker();

    $('#time_start').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({

            date:false,
            shortTime: false,
            format: 'HH:mm:ss'
    });

$('#date_end').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({

    date:true,
    shortTime: false,
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
});

$('#delete').on('click', function(){
   var x = $(this);
   var delete_url = x.attr('data-href')+'/'+x.attr('data-id');

$.ajax({
url:delete_url,
    type:'Delete',
    success: function(result){
    alert(result.message);
    },
    error: function(result){
        alert(result.message);
    }
});
});

</script>
</html>
```

network tab:
[image]

This my error log (today's activity):

```
192.168.1.7 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:33 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2586
192.168.103.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:52 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2592
192.168.10.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:43 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2590
192.168.56.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:45 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2588
192.168.103.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2590
192.168.1.7 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:38 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2588
192.168.10.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:41 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2588
192.168.56.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:47 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2590
fe80::c18:701:c2b7:3d43 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:55 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2646
fe80::c18:701:c2b7:3d43 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:56 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2648
fe80::1510:b6c4:b641:3086 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:58 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2646
fe80::1510:b6c4:b641:3086 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:19:59 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2648
fe80::b58d:e8c4:8757:9de3 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:20:01 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2646
fe80::b58d:e8c4:8757:9de3 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:20:02 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2648
fe80::d524:23aa:32e3:3027 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:20:04 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2646
fe80::d524:23aa:32e3:3027 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:20:05 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2648
fe80::c18:701:c2b7:3d43 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:20:06 +0100] "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1" 400 444
fe80::1510:b6c4:b641:3086 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:20:06 +0100] "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1" 400 446
fe80::b58d:e8c4:8757:9de3 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:20:07 +0100] "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1" 400 444
fe80::d524:23aa:32e3:3027 - - [10/Jul/2017:13:20:07 +0100] "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1" 400 446
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:21:44 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2584
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:21:47 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:28:29 +0100] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 5704
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:28:34 +0100] "GET /css/app.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:28:34 +0100] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:28:34 +0100] "GET /js/app.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:29:02 +0100] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 336
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:29:07 +0100] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 5966
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:30:43 +0100] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 336
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:30:44 +0100] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 5966
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:30:53 +0100] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 332
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:30:54 +0100] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 200 11741
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:30:55 +0100] "GET /status_images/KznUnppb_eventhomepagepicture.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 22623
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:01 +0100] "GET /calendar HTTP/1.1" 200 12596
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:02 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:02 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:02 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:02 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:02 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:02 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:02 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 84380
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:02 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 36868
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:02 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap-colorpicker/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:02 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:03 +0100] "GET /events?start=2017-06-25&end=2017-08-06&_=1499693462700 HTTP/1.1" 200 203
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:31:08 +0100] "DELETE /events/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 47304
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:33:23 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:33:23 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:33:23 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/jquery.min.map HTTP/1.1" 404 33257
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:39:57 +0100] "DELETE /events/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 47304
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:43:16 +0100] "GET /calendar HTTP/1.1" 200 12596
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:43:18 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/jquery.min.map HTTP/1.1" 404 33257
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:43:18 +0100] "GET /events?start=2017-06-25&end=2017-08-06&_=1499694197455 HTTP/1.1" 200 203
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:43:22 +0100] "DELETE /events/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 47304
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:51:08 +0100] "GET /calendar HTTP/1.1" 200 12596
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:51:09 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/jquery.min.map HTTP/1.1" 404 33257
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:14:51:10 +0100] "GET /events?start=2017-06-25&end=2017-08-06&_=1499694669503 HTTP/1.1" 500 41648
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:15:11:02 +0100] "GET /calendar HTTP/1.1" 200 12596
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:15:11:04 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/jquery.min.map HTTP/1.1" 404 33257
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:15:11:05 +0100] "GET /events?start=2017-06-25&end=2017-08-06&_=1499695864126 HTTP/1.1" 200 203
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:15:11:09 +0100] "DELETE /events/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 47304
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:15:20:35 +0100] "GET /calendar HTTP/1.1" 200 12596
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:15:20:36 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/jquery.min.map HTTP/1.1" 404 33257
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:15:20:37 +0100] "GET /events?start=2017-06-25&end=2017-08-06&_=1499696436403 HTTP/1.1" 500 41648
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:15:20:43 +0100] "GET /calendar HTTP/1.1" 200 12596
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:15:20:45 +0100] "GET /vendor2/seguce92/jquery.min.map HTTP/1.1" 404 33257
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:15:20:46 +0100] "GET /events?start=2017-06-25&end=2017-08-06&_=1499696444995 HTTP/1.1" 200 203
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2017:15:20:56 +0100] "DELETE /events/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 47304
```

Screenshot from fiddler:

[image]

Screenshot of Error:
[image]

web.php :

```
 Route::get('/calendar', function () {
        return view('calendar');
    });

    Route::resource('events', 'EventsController', ['only' => ['index', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']]);
```

Comment: Do you have the details of the `500` error: like the content of the "error page" or something from the web server logs ?

Comment: 500 errors are on the server side. Have you looked at the server's logs?

Comment: @j08691 no I haven't looked into the logs at all

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I have the image with the error with more details,if that's what you are looking for

Comment: Try opening the Network tab when running the page. The response often holds the 500 in its entirety.

Comment: @Rachel It's not details that you provide, it's `call stack`. `Error logs` from the server will be useful.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ So in my case I'm using xampp ,well I have gone into Logs in there but I could not find any errors that , looked into the all logs type options ,I'm guessing that you are talking about `Apache(error.log)`

Comment: @Rachel You are right. Without logs, we canot help you to find what's happening. What about the `Network` tab in your browser or can you use a tool like `Fiddler` to catch the `HTTP` streams ?

Comment: THat's the access log. Errors won't show up there.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Sorry, I have found today's activity(from aux.access.log) in the error log ,please have looked and I added a photo of the network tab,yes I ll have a look the `Fiddler` tool now .

Comment: @Rachel It seems that the error commes form this url `/events?start=2017-06-25&end=2017-08-06&_=1499696436403`, right ? Can you open it in your web browser to see what it displays ?

Comment: Added screenshot of what I got from fiddler ,and this this what I got from that link `[Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "events" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No such host is known`

Comment: Have a look in your browser and see what you get when you go directly to: `http://social.com/events/2` - is there an event for that id?

Comment: @beingalex Its says `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` ,it's not allowing the delete method, I think the problem is in my web,php class  ,I have put a screenshot above of the error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@taha is on the right track, but **you** must add the hidden field, Laravel will not do it for you.  Most browsers do not support `DELETE`, so you need to [use method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing) by adding a hidden field to your form, or directly to the POSTed data in JS as you are doing:

```
$.ajax({
    url:delete_url,
    type:'POST',
    data: '_method=DELETE',
    success: function(result){
        alert(result.message);
    },
    error: function(result){
        alert(result.message);
    }
});
```

Also, make sure you have the corresponding delete route set up in `app/Http/routes.php`, eg:

```
Route::delete('/events/{event}', 'Controller@method');
```

Comment: See the thing is I'm working through this example :https://github.com/seguce92/fullcalendar-laravel ,and non of the above that you suggested are not used to create the delete option and it uses one route for everything `Route::resource('events', 'EventsController', ['only' => ['index', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']]);` .In that example this all is not necessary so it must be something else wrong

Comment: OK, the `resource()` route will include the delete route.  That's fine.  You still need the method spoofing though, as I described.  Have you added it? If yes, can you confirm via devtools that it is being POSTed to your controller?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you have included `jquery.min.js` twice in your view, once as `Html::script('vendor2/seguce92/jquery.min.js')`, and once as `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`.  You only need one, two will cause problems.  Assuming it is valid and includes the file correctly, keep the `Html::script()` one at the bottom of your view and remove the other.

Comment: I re-read your code and realised you don't actually have a delete form, sorry.  In that case you have nowhere to add the method spoof as I previously described. I've updated my answer to do it in the JS.

Comment: Thanks for not giving up on this one :)

Comment: Glad we cracked it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in *calendar.blade.php* (if it's not intentional) you forgot `{{ Form::open(...) }}` and `{{ Form::close(...) }}` inside the *delete modal*

> Laravel "fakes" methods browsers cannot handle.

The form methods `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE` cannot be handled by most browsers. So what Laravel does is make the `method="POST"` and adds a hidden field.

```
$('#delete').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this);
    var delete_url = x.attr('data-href');
    var id = x.attr('data-id');

    $.ajax({
        url:delete_url,
        type:'POST',
        data: id,
        success: function(result){

        // $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvent', x.attr('data-id'));

        alert(result.message);
        },
        error: function(result){
            alert(result.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Then you should receive the request at :

`Route::post('events/{id}', EventsController@destroy)`

Comment: I got this error in the console when I tried that `jquery.min.js:4 POST https://social.com/events/2 405 (Method Not Allowed)` and also leaving the `{{ Form::open(...) }}` intentional

Comment: @Rachel: seems to be a path problem! do you have a 'post' route set up for that?

Comment: I have as `resource` you can have a look above I have posted web.php class in my question

Comment: **Method Not Allowed** exception indicates that a route doesn't exist for the HTTP method you are requesting. make sure you have a `Route::post(...)` to receive the request